# Where do files in dataDir exist in Android?

Tags: java, android

I am working on an Android App where a file is given its location like the code given below.

The method is like this:

```
public boolean log(ApplicationInfo  aplinfo)
{
    ApplicationInfo objAppinfo;
    objAppinfo = apinfo;

    _strFilePath = objAppinfo.dataDir;
    _strFilePath += "/";
}
```

Where `Appicationinfo` is my activity name.

When I see in logcat I am getting file path as

```
09-07 06:34:41.355: INFO/System.out(525): 
  FileName::::::::::/data/data/com.andr.activity/Info_SA1.txt
```

My doubt is where can I find this file, where does this file exist?

When I am trying to read the contents of this file, then the contents that are written in to this file are also visible. But I am not able to find the physical location of the file.

Where does data/data/com.andr.activity path exists?

Can anyone help me in sorting out this issue?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This lives in the android filesystem, which is different from your computer's file system. To view the files in android filesystem, use adb shell on the command prompt. Run:
adb shell ls /data/data/com.andr.activity. Make sure your device/emulator is connected before you do this.
Or if you are using eclipse, switch to DDMS view and check out the file explorer.

To View file:

```
adb shell
```

Inside shell use:

```
cd /data/data/com.andr.activity
cat filename
```

Or Use `adb pull` to copy file to your computer's local filesystem and then view it using any editor. Read more about `adb pull` [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#copyfiles)

Comment: Thank you very much my file is found there? My emulator is connected and using DDMS I foound my fiel.But how to view that file? I am trying to right click and open but notable to view that file.

Comment: DDMS does not support view file. I have modified my answer above to add how to view file.